# Entity Framework 6 Code First Concurrency

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am looking at using Entity Framework 6 for a new project.

When we develop our tables we add an update counter of type int, and when performing an update we check that it hasn't changed and increment it on a successful update.

From what I've read I can do the check by adding a ConcurrencyCheck attribute to the update counter property, but how do I perform the increment on successful update?

Or should I just use a Rowversion column instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/04/tutorial-series-for-entity-framework-6-mvc-5-published.aspx) contains links to a number of EF6 and MVC guides. There is one in particular you should check out - [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework 6](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). The guide is using an ASP.Net MVC project, but the database principles should apply to almost any type of project.

In short, though, if you use a `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute then you don't have to update any counter yourself - but it adds more overhead to your application's database operations because under the hood EF will be extrapolating every SQL query to include concurrency checks for properties that you have applied the `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute to. If you have a very large table (lots of columns), this can cause slower application performance.

The better way would be for you to use `TimeStamp` attribute on a byte array property in your code-first class (or if you are using Fluent API you set `IsConcurrencyToken()` on the property). Then, if there is a concurrency conflict EF will throw a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` - it's up to you to then catch it and handle it accordingly.

Comment: So, adding a ConcurrencyCheck attribute to a single column should cause EF to increment it as well? I'm assuming one column won't cause the slow performance like you described.

Comment: @ScottD yes , but then concurrency will only be checked for that one column. Its usually better to use the timestamp

Comment: @rwisch45 I'd say that only depends on your use case. Row versioning can lead to a very frustrating situation where you cannot differentiate between critical and non-critical writes. To say that it is usually better to use row versioning over anything else without proper context is fallacious.